# Docker-compose setup mongodb with data and a nodejs server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

i want to spin up a whole nodejs/mongodb environment with docker compose.i created a mongodump into radcupDevSample.json which i want to mongo restore i a new mongodb container. After this i want a new node container with my api linked to the mondodb container with the sample data.

i have the following files:

**1. docker-compose.yml:**

```
db:
  image: mongo
  ports: 
    - "27017:27017"`

mongo-importer:
      build: .

web: 
     build: web
     links:
            - db 
     ports:
            - "3000:3000"
      volumes: 
             - ./src:/home/env
      environment:
            NODE_ENV: development
```

**2. web Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN git clone https://sdsds-oauth-basic@github.com/jdklfj /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app/src
RUN npm install
CMD "npm start"
EXPOSE 3000
```

**3. "." dockerfile**

```
FROM mongo
COPY radcupDevSample.json /radcupDevSample.json
CMD mongorestore -h db /radcupDevSample.json
```

I used this answer mentioned here: 
[How do I seed a mongo database using docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210973/how-do-i-seed-a-mongo-database-using-docker-compose)

My problem is: if i try `docker-compose up` i get this error:

```
docker-compose up
radcupbackend_db_1 is up-to-date
Building web
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/compose/compose/cli/main.py", line 54, in main
  File "/compose/compose/cli/docopt_command.py", line 23, in sys_dispatch
  File "/compose/compose/cli/docopt_command.py", line 26, in dispatch
  File "/compose/compose/cli/main.py", line 171, in perform_command
  File "/compose/compose/cli/main.py", line 587, in up
  File "/compose/compose/project.py", line 313, in up
  File "/compose/compose/service.py", line 404, in execute_convergence_plan
  File "/compose/compose/service.py", line 303, in create_container
  File "/compose/compose/service.py", line 326, in ensure_image_exists
  File "/compose/compose/service.py", line 723, in build
  File "/compose/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 41, in build
TypeError: You must specify a directory to build in path
docker-compose returned -1
```

***Have someone a "hint" why i get this errors ? Or maybe could someone help me out to set up this environment ?***

Thank you!

PS. building the 2 Dockerfiles separately don't throw any error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the docker is unable to find web/ directory from your current directory where you are running `docker-compose up`

Does your structure look like this?

```
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-compose-mongo$ tree .
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── radcupDevSample.json
├── src
└── web
    └── Dockerfile

2 directories, 4 files
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-compose-mongo$
```

I created this kind of structure and then when I ran my build,

```
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/docker-compose-mongo$ docker-compose up
dockercomposemongo_db_1 is up-to-date
Starting dockercomposemongo_web_1
Building mongo-importer
Step 1 : FROM mongo
 ---> 94a166215fe3
...
```

In order to make sure everything is in order, I recommend you to run a `docker-compose build --no-cache` first from the same directory, this will ensure that you start from a clean slate.

```
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/docker-compose-mongo$ docker-compose build --no-cache
db uses an image, skipping
Building web
Step 1 : FROM node
 ---> ac9b478bfbbd
...
```

And then run a `docker-compose up`

Please let me know how it went.

Comment: thanks a lot, the problem was i haven't unterstand the docker file style with directors. naming a dockerfile into web won't work. after i created a web/ Dir and a new Dockerfile everything works as expected.