# How to use docker with mongo to achieve replication and with opening authentication

Tags: mongodb, authentication, docker, replication

I want to use docker run a vm mongodb, at the same time, the mongo configure file use my own defined configure file to archive replication and open authentication.

Scanning some files but don't resolve the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The [docker mongo image](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo) has a [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/3.2/docker-entrypoint.sh) it [calls in the Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/3.2/Dockerfile#L77-L79)

Check if you can:

- create your own image which would create the right user and restart mongo with authentication on: see "[`umputun/mongo-auth`](https://github.com/umputun/mongo-auth)" and its [`init.sh` script](https://github.com/umputun/mongo-auth/blob/master/init.sh)
- or mount a `createUser.js` script in `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.
  See "[how to make a mongo docker container with auth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43430199/6309)"

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it.