# How to import data to mongodb container and creating an image

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I spent a lot of time on a task which seems a simple one. I want to run a monogodb container. then copy csv file in to the container or execute a command from docker file to import the csv file into the mongodb database. I tried using RUN, script.sh but nothing is working. Please help.
I want to automate the task and when I copy the data, I will make a new image for my automated task.

Here is the Dockerfile I have.

```
FROM mongo
RUN mkdir -p /app/data
WORKDIR /app/data
COPY gene.csv /app/data
COPY script.sh /app/data
EXPOSE 27017
# CMD ["/app/data/script.sh"]
```

The script file is

```
#! /bin/sh 
mongoimport -d Gene -c genes --type csv --file gene.csv --headerline
```

Comment: Why are you using a bash script, why not use node?

Comment: Why @DanGreen-Leipciger? I can't see any possible reason to choose node for such a ridiculously lightweight task, but I have no expertise in it so genuine question.

Comment: It's just quick and easy, if you already use it. Runs by default in cli, `$node myscript.js`. It also takes no configuration and runs on any machine.

Comment: Also, MongoDB has an amazing node interface and all of the said commands are available. Plus, the OP would have access to all of the node tools available on NPM should the needs grow more complex.

Comment: This is so common thing to do, I wonder why its not already on the net. What actually I am doing is: I am creating a web app and I have written a docker-compose.yml file. If I am able to enter the data and make an image, all the users will do is docker-compose up and browse to localhost:3000/genes to see the data.

Comment: @Dan Green-Leipciger could you please write in detail your answer.

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger I guess. I mean in a mongo container I don't see any reason you'd have node, or see any reason that node's interface with mongo would give me such an unbelievable experience over bash just for running a single command, for all the extra bloat it would put in the image. Just my 2/c though.

Comment: @johnharris85  Fair enough

Answer (score 2):

Too late, maybe help to others.

```
    FROM mongo
    RUN mkdir -p /app/data
    WORKDIR /app/data
    COPY gene.csv /app/data
    COPY script.sh /app/data
    CMD ["mongod", "&&", "mongoimport", "-d", "Gene", "-c", "Genes", "--file", "gene.csv", "--headerline"]
```

Comment: I will check it out. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This answer solves *a* problem, but not *the* problem, as apparently mongo has to be running for any of this to work. In that case a custom entrypoint is probably the way to go.

Using `RUN` is the right way, as then when you use `CMD` you can actually run the Mongo process. However your problem is with your `COPY` instructions.

```
COPY gene.csv /app/data
COPY script.sh /app/data
```

These lines need a `/` on the end, as right now they say 'copy this file from my host, to be this file in my container'. Whereas you're trying to say 'copy this file from my host, *into* this *folder* in my container. They should read as below (but can be simplified even further, see final `Dockerfile` at the end):

```
COPY gene.csv /app/data/
COPY script.sh /app/data/
```

Your script will then run if you put it in a `RUN` instruction and that layer will be committed into the image, then you can have a `CMD` at the end to run mongo (or just leave it blank and inherit the default `ENTRYPOINT` / `CMD` from the parent (`mongo`) image. So the full `Dockerfile` becomes:

```
FROM mongo
WORKDIR /app/data        # This will be created if it doesn't exist
COPY gene.csv .
COPY script.sh .
RUN chmod +x script.sh && sync && ./script.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for help. For the above docker file I got the following error
Step 5/5 : RUN ./script.sh
 ---> Running in 1d385c7df879
/bin/sh: 1: ./script.sh: Permission denied
The command '/bin/sh -c ./script.sh' returned a non-zero code: 126

Comment: I got this error now 
Step 5/5 : RUN chmod +x script.sh && sync && ./script.sh
 ---> Running in 6de14ed40581
2017-04-23T19:45:30.083+0000 [#.......................] Gene.genes 4.00KB/57.6KB (6.9%)
2017-04-23T19:45:30.598+0000 [#.......................] Gene.genes 4.00KB/57.6KB (6.9%)
2017-04-23T19:45:30.598+0000 Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
2017-04-23T19:45:30.598+0000 imported 0 documents
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x script.sh && sync && ./script.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: I read somewhere an hour ago that you have to restart db or something like that. Dont know why they made it so complicated.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with mongo. Does mongo need to be running for this to work? If so then we'll need a different solution.

Comment: If we give FROM mongo
CMD ["usr/bin/mongod", "--smallfiles"] before executing the script. Same error,

Comment: Right, because `CMD` is a runtime instruction. You will likely need to create a custom entrypoint that starts mongo then runs your mongoimport statement.

Comment: Any idea, how :)

Comment: About to go out, but will try and edit the answer later.

Comment: Many thanks for your help ;) Let see if I get it there :)]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that but through another container. Whose job is to insert the data in to the mongodb database container and exit. For more details check the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210973/how-do-i-seed-a-mongo-database-using-docker-compose). I changed the JSON file with my csv file and the command which import it, although I found that mongodb works better with json.