# Mongodb Docker - Creating initial users and setting up initial structures

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to build a mongodb container with a user and basic database structure already setup (from Dockerfile).

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:latest

RUN mongo localhost:27017 "db.help()"
```

(minified it for testing purposes).

I keep getting the error:

```
connecting to: localhost:27017
2017-06-01T14:49:34.353+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-06-01T14:49:34.353+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server localhost:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

...and the container fails to build. I am not even sure how to check the logs since I am building from Dockerfile and once the container fails to build, there's no way to go inside to check logs.

However, if I remove that RUN command and manually do:

```
docker -exec -it mongodb_container bash
mongo
> db.help()
```

...it works.

I have tried setting ownership to mongodb:mongodb and tried moving log and db path to ~/db dir without success.

PS: I am using docker-compose. Would like to do this with docker-compose so developers do not have to manage things themselves.

Here is docker-compose segment:

```
mongodb:
  build: ./mongodb
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
```

**EDIT:**

If I change it to `0.0.0.0:27017`, then I get this error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
connecting to: 0.0.0.0:27017
2017-06-01T15:52:52.806+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 0.0.0.0:27017, address resolved to 0.0.0.0 :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

**EDIT2:**

When I try with following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:latest

RUN mkdir -p /data/db2 \
    && echo "dbpath = /data/db2" > /etc/mongodb.conf \
    && chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db2

COPY . /data/db2

RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db2
```

MongoDB starts initially, but then exits with output:

```
mongodb_1    | 2017-06-01T15:55:52.955+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=64a317041edd
mongodb_1    | 2017-06-01T15:55:52.956+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.4
mongodb_1    | 2017-06-01T15:55:52.956+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 888390515874a9debd1b6c5d36559ca86b44babd
mongodb_1    | 2017-06-01T15:55:52.956+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
mongodb_1    | 2017-06-01T15:55:52.956+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mongodb_1    | 2017-06-01T15:55:52.956+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
mongodb_1    | 2017-06-01T15:55:52.956+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
mongodb_1    | 2017-06-01T15:55:52.956+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian81
mongodb_1    | 2017-06-01T15:55:52.956+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
mongodb_1    | 2017-06-01T15:55:52.956+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
mongodb_1    | 2017-06-01T15:55:52.956+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
mongodb_1    | 2017-06-01T15:55:52.964+0000 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Operation not permitted
mongodb_1    | 2017-06-01T15:55:52.964+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578 at src/mongo/util/net/listen.cpp 194
mongodb_1    | 2017-06-01T15:55:52.964+0000 I -        [initandlisten]
mongodb_1    |
mongodb_1    | ***aborting after fassert() failure
mongodb_1    |
mongodb_1    |
stuff_mongodb_1 exited with code 14
```

Comment: What port is Mongo listening in inside the container? Seems like it doesn't bind to port 27017.

Comment: Afaik the parent Dockerfile does make it listen on 27017/27018/27019. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yup sorry, didn't parse the command line with the localhost:27017. Might try binding to 0.0.0.0:27017

Comment: Tried, says `Couldn't connect to server`. Also, please check edits above in post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a slight different approach. You can feed mongo with data whenever it starts at first time. You can accomplish that using an auxiliar container `mongo-seed`.

See this approach:

```
version: "2"

mongodb:
  image: mongo
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
mongo-seed:
  image: mongo
  command: mongoimport --host mongodb --db example-db --collection MyDummyCollection --type json --file /init.json --jsonArray
  volumes:
    - ./init.json:/init.json
```

init.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "Joe Smith",
    "email": "jsmith@gmail.com",
    "age": 40,
    "admin": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Jen Ford",
    "email": "jford@gmail.com",
    "age": 45,
    "admin": true
  }
]
```

Run as:

```
docker-compose up
docker-compose exec mongodb mongo
> use example-db
> db.MyDummyCollection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("592f5496fcdcafc0a8e0e0c8"), "name" : "Joe Smith", "email" : "jsmith@gmail.com", "age" : 40, "admin" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("592f5496fcdcafc0a8e0e0c9"), "name" : "Jen Ford", "email" : "jford@gmail.com", "age" : 45, "admin" : true }
```

I took the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210973/how-do-i-seed-a-mongo-database-using-docker-compose), but I've improved it without the need of a Dockerfile for the seed.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a shot later