# How do I run shell commands from myApp(python) container in myData(mongodb) container?

Tags: shell, docker, mongoimport

I have two containers one running `python` and other one running `mongodb`. Now I want to run `mongoimport` command from my application container.

So how do I do it?

Comment: You can use ```docker exec -it name_container or id_container bash or sh``` so when you are inside of container of mongodb use ```mongo import```

Answer (score 0):

[`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) should be reserved for debugging purposes.

Ideally, you would run `mongoimport` at build time from your `Dockerfile`, in order to make an image dedicated to seed your mongo database.
For instance, look at "[How do I seed a mongo database using docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33397913/6309)"

That way, you avoid any *manual* runtime operation.

If you must have a regular runtime operation, then you need to add to your image a [`cron`, as I described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37458519/6309).
That way, you can execute that `mongoimport` on a regular basis, during the time the container is running.

Comment: The application is such that when new files get added it should be imported in database. Files would only be added at an interval yet I would like to automate that process.

Comment: @SamipKothari OK. I have edited the answer accordingly.