# Import Data on MongoDB using Docker-Compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

There are many sites that show how to import data to a mongodb using the below docker-compose method but mine is not finding the db server.

[How do I seed a mongo database using docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210973/how-do-i-seed-a-mongo-database-using-docker-compose)
https://gist.github.com/jschwarty/6f9907e2871d1ece5bde53d259c18d5f
https://docs.codefresh.io/v1.0/docs/import-data-to-mongodb-in-composition

Wondering if something has changed making this not work any longer.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --smallfiles
    ports:
      - 27017

  mongo_seed:
    build: mongo-seed/.
    links:
      - mongodb
```

**mongo-seed/Dockerfile**

```
FROM mongo

COPY census.json /census.json

CMD mongoimport --host mongodb --db test --collection census --type json --file /census.json --jsonArray
```

**mongo-seed/census.json**

```
[
 {
   "Geography": "Abbeville city, Alabama",
   "Census": "2688"
 }
]
```

**ERROR after *docker-compose up***

```
mongodb_1     | 2018-01-09T21:57:14.353+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
mongo_seed_1  | 2018-01-10T00:19:58.286+0000    [........................] test.census 0B/1KB (0.0%)
mongo_seed_1  | 2018-01-10T00:19:58.332+0000    [........................] test.census 0B/1KB (0.0%)
mongo_seed_1  | 2018-01-10T00:19:58.332+0000    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
mongo_seed_1  | 2018-01-10T00:19:58.332+0000    imported 0 documents
```

In the *mongoimport* statement, I have tried using different host names: *mongodb_1*, *127.0.0.1*, *localhost*.

I have read that if *replSet* is set it can give this error but I'm not setting *replSet* unless it's default in which case I don't know how it disable it.

I have also tried *mongorestore* instead of *mongoimport* but get the same error.

I have read since *link* is deprecated in Docker that maybe environmental variables are no longer working. Not sure if that is true or happening here.

Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I ended up removing the Dockerfile, adding the commands in a bash script, then calling the script from the docker-compose file. Used a script rather than one command in the docker-compose file because I'm importing several files thus several commands that are not shown in my example. I needed to use mongo:3.2.6 to make this work. There may be other versions but this one works for sure.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.2.6
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  mongo_seed:
    image: mongo:3.2.6
    links:
      - mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-seed:/mongo-seed
    command:
      /mongo-seed/import.sh
```

**/mongo-seed/import.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash

mongoimport --host mongodb --db test --collection census --type json --file /mongo-seed/census.json --jsonArray
```

Comment: if you wanted to also run another script like mongo --host mongodb /mongo-seed/createuser.js, that just contains a use admin; db.createUser({etc..}... how would you incorporate that into that import.sh file?

Comment: I am geeting `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 354: /mongo-seed/import.sh: Permission denied
`.any help

Comment: For Permission denied: `chmod +x mongo-seed/import.sh`

Comment: I got the same error that you had after I did what you suggested here. But by removing the version number 3.2.6, everything worked fine

Comment: I'm always getting:
error connecting to host: `could not connect to server: connection() error occured during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.`

Even if I'm running the command manually inside the `mongodb` container !!

Comment: @ebramShehata I solved this with `--authenticationDatabase=admin` and specifying user/pass on the mongoimiport commandline. Aloso had to add environment variables for the mongodb container `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD`. Not recommended in production but works on my local project

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing that Permission denied because you didn't mark the `.sh` file as executable. Just run `chmod +x file.sh` and then run again the whole docker-compose up.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of info about (apparently) an "old" way of doing it. Using a bash script didn't look appealing to me either, so I decided to dig deeper and have found a "proper" solution. Here it is:

https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo (section "Initializing a fresh instance")

Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42917632/2761550 (this one was surprisingly hard to find using search engines)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I put my json file into the data folder

```
mongoimport:
image: library/mongo:latest
container_name: my-import
volumes:
  - ./data/orders.json:/src/data/orders.json
command: mongoimport --host mongodb --db my-mongo --collection orders --file /src/data/orders.json


mongodb:
image: library/mongo:latest
container_name: my-mongo
ports:
  - 27017:27017
depends_on:
  - mongoimport
restart: always
```