# How to run mongorestore in docker-compose project before start of application server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose project for Rails depends on mongo. I need to run mongorestore during build before CMD in dockerfile runs the rails server. How I can do that?

I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/66069362/4011757 but it doesn't start the mongorestore.

The server doesn't start says collections not found needed to start it. So it is necessary to have mongorestore before start of the server

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.3.0

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs npm
RUN npm install --global coffeescript
WORKDIR /
COPY Gemfile /Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /Gemfile.lock

RUN mkdir -p /log && touch /log/development.log
RUN gem install bundler -v "1.17.3"
RUN bundle install
COPY . /
CMD ["sh", "-c", "bundle exec padrino start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3.4'
services: 
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2.4
    container_name: 'tickets-mongo'
    volumes: 
      - ./mongorestore.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongorestore.sh
      - ./db:/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis
    depends_on: 
      - mongo
    ports: 
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/var/lib/redis
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.9.2
    container_name: 'tickets-elasticsearch'
    environment: 
      - discovery.type=single-node
    depends_on: 
      - redis
    ports: 
      - 9200:9200
    volumes: 
      - elasticsearch_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  app-worker:
    env_file: 
      - .env_development.env
    build: .
    container_name: tickets-worker
    depends_on: 
      - elasticsearch
    links: 
      - mongo:mongo
      - redis:redis
      - elasticsearch:elasticsearch
  app:
    env_file: 
      - .env_development.env
    build: .
    container_name: tickets-web
    depends_on: 
      - app-worker
    links: 
      - mongo:mongo
      - redis:redis
      - elasticsearch:elasticsearch
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
volumes: 
  mongo: {}
  redis_data: {}
  elasticsearch_data: {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update:

I was afraid that `depends_on` or `links` might not work in this case. The reason is, Compose does start `mongo` before it starts either `app-worker` or `app`. But it doesn't wait until `mongo` service is in `READY` state to start the dependant services.

Basically, what you need is to find a way to tell Compose to wait until `mongo` service is in READY state.

The solution is described in [Control startup and shutdown order in Compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order)

I hope this helps you. Cheers  !!!

---

Could you try adding `depends_on` in `app-worker` for `mongo` service. The `docker-compose.yml` file should look like:

```yaml
...
  app-worker:
    env_file: 
      - .env_development.env
    build: .
    container_name: tickets-worker
    depends_on: 
      - elasticsearch
      - mongo
    links:
...
```

Although, I'm a little confused as to why you have the same context in both `app` and `app-worker` services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I will let you know if it works. The answer to your question is `app` has background separate server `app-worker` and `app` depends on `app-worker` to run. They are essentially the same so have same context

Comment: How did it go? Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: Yes that didn't resolve the issue... I am doing restore after it starts

Comment: I was afraid that this would happen. I have updated my answer with a new solution.

Comment: Thanks looking in to it

Comment: I haven't looked into it as the task was time-boxed and for now, I restore db after build

Comment: No worries. Try it later. Hope this will work for you 