# dockerfile - CMD mongoimport

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongo-shell, mongoimport

```
FROM mongo

COPY . /data/db2/

# Expose the MongoDB port
EXPOSE 27017
CMD mongoimport --db test --collection data --file /data/db2/data.json
```

The copy command copy data.json file

when Im trying to put the mongoimport in the CMD directive Im getting this error:

docker logs:

```
error connecting to host: failed to connect to mongodb://localhost/: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: localhost:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: connect: connection refused }, ] }
```

when Im trying to connect to container shell, and run mongosh I get this error:

```
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

the weird part is when Im not putting that CMD Directive, I tried to connect to the container shell and run this command, It worked just fined.

any ideas?

Comment: What you want to achieve with CMD? Connect to the container and access db instance?

Comment: @RichardRublev I want to start a mongodb container that already has a db inside it with the data.json file on startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `CMD mongoimport ..` you overwrite the original which is `CMD ["mongod"]`, which would start the database. So your current example never starts the database and can therefore not connect.

If you want to to initialize/restore a database at startup there is a `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory in the container image you can use.
Checkout
[Import Data on MongoDB using Docker-Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178870/import-data-on-mongodb-using-docker-compose) or [How to create a DB for MongoDB container on start up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912755/how-to-create-a-db-for-mongodb-container-on-start-up) for a couple of examples.