# Mongo + seeder in Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

As part of a big project, I need add to this project docker, with mongo and a kind of seeder for this mongo, I was following this post [How do I seed a mongo database using docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210973/how-do-i-seed-a-mongo-database-using-docker-compose) but everytime when I try to launch I always get the same error **Failed: error connecting to DB server: no reachable servers** I put all the files for this situation here https://github.com/aasanchez/mongodb-seeder ONLY the referent to this bug... someone have any idea about how to connect, I think my problem is in the connection URL but I don't know how to fix it
[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

First problem, you url in your CMD is wrong, do like

```
CMD mongoimport --host mongodb -p 27017 --db reach-engine --collection users --type json --file ./data.json --jsonArray
```

Second, when launched by docker-compose, the dependency implied by `links` (which is deprecated) only ensures start up order, not your MongoDB's readiness. So you need to wait a few seconds before `mongoimport`.

All in all

```
CMD sleep 10 && mongoimport --host mongodb -p 27017 --db reach-engine --collection users --type json --file ./data.json --jsonArray
```

Note `sleep 10` is only a simple hack, consider use wait-for-it.sh for complexe dependency.