# How to utilize a Mongo seed container to import users to admin?

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

Mongo seed container comes in handy when we need to pre-insert some collections before initializing a mongo container. For instance, like the solution in this question:[How do I seed a mongo database using docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210973/how-do-i-seed-a-mongo-database-using-docker-compose)

But what about importing users to admin database with the following Docker set up:

1. `docker-compose.yml`:

   ```
   version: '3.4'
   services:
     mongodb:
       image: mongo:latest
       ports: 
       - "27017:27017"
       environment:
       # provide your credentials here
       - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
       - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
       container_name: mongodb 
     mongodb_seed:
       build: mongodb_seed
       links:
       - mongodb
   ```

   with this setting, `mongodb_seed` can be used to insert ready data into `mongodb` right before initializing
2. `Dockerfile` of `mongodb_seed`:

   ```
   FROM mongo:latest
   WORKDIR /tmp
   COPY users.json .
   COPY insert_users.js .
   COPY import.sh .
   CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source import.sh"]
   ```

   with this setting, the `import.sh` can be used to execute the `insert_users.js`containing code like:

   ```
   use admin
   db.createUser()
   ```

   in this case the `import.sh` might look like:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   mongo -u root -p root --authenticationDatabase admin insert_users.js
   ```

But this approach got *connection refused* in the log:

```
    mongodb_seed_1  | connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/? authSource=admin&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
    mongodb_seed_1  | 2019-04-03T07:39:27.902+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
    mongodb_seed_1  | connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
    mongodb_seed_1  | @(connect):2:6
    mongodb_seed_1  | exception: connect failed
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: As a service, MongoDB does take some time to start. So any scripting needs to take this into account.

Comment: @NeilLunn Note that I used one mongo container as the seed, and I tried to add a sleep command to wait for about half a minute before running the mongo cli command, but still got the same error. So seems that when running the CMD in the mongo seed container, the mongod service is never started at all

Comment: If you actually check both the question and answer you've been linked to, then you should notice that your own configuration completely misses asking the service to start. Those examples actually do that.